# Can I search inside multiple attributes with a single form field? (Magento AdvancedSearch)

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to modify Magento's AdvancedSearch but I haven't found a way to search for all the "text" fields using a single input. I can show inputs to allow searching for something inside Name or Description or ShortDescription, but ***is there a way to show the customer a "Text" input and make it search inside all the fields at once?***

If I use the full text search instead then I'd have no way to search for the text only for products within a certain price or belonging to a specific category, right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select additional filters before performing a search query with full text search, but full text search allows you to enable layered navigation on the results page.

Layered navigation gives abilities to filter results by price range, categories, and product attributes those are marked as "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation".

Comment: Layered navigation is good, but at least for my users it's not totally useful, as they expect to filter everything from the start (once Layered navigation kicks in the results, it's quite intuitive, of course, the problem is the initial UI).

On the other hand, if I could query all the text fields at once, *and* still have the other filters of AdvancedSearch it would be perfect.